# Adding alternate colours to the table

Tags: php, css

i was given a task to create a multiplication table using PHP for loop as below
[Multiplication table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfK6I.png)

I've done the php code, but i've trouble adding colour to it.

NOTE:

Use CSS3 selectors and properties in an external CSS file

Do not use the :nth-child() selector in this task

The first submission that i did was rejected and do really need help.

```
<table border = "1">
    <p>For loop</p>
    <?php
    for ($i=1;  $i <= 12; $i++){
            echo "<tr class='row'> \n";             
                
            for ($j=1;  $j <= 12; $j++){
                $p = $i*$j;
                if ($i == $j){
                    echo "<td>".$p."</td>";
                } else{
                    echo "<th>".$p."</th>";
                }

            }
    }
    ?>
      </table>
```

Comment: Well the green cells could be done using `:first-child`. And for the red cells in the diagonal, it would probably make the most sense to give those a specific class (based on $i==$j), and apply the formatting based on that then.

Comment: Yes I DID IT!!! thanks for that
Anyway, still stuck with that light blue colour on every row 2nd row

Comment: If you are not supposed to use `:nth-child` for that part, then you can also give the table rows a class, based on whether $i is odd or even (use `$i % 2` to test for that.)

Comment: Yes that what i was planning to do but unfortunately couldnt get it right. Do you mind to give me some hint about the code

Comment: For example, using the ternary operator: `echo "<tr class='row ".($i % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even')."'> \n";` - that should give the rows alternating `odd` and `even` classes, so you can format the cells in these rows using something like `.odd td {...}` then.